# Reviewing first questions/answers

Tags: discussion

When [reviewing questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions) the blurb mentions:

> These are the **first questions a new user has ever asked** on TeX - LaTeX.

When [reviewing answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers) the blurb mentions:

> These are the **first answers a new user has ever submitted** to TeX - LaTeX.

However, if I understand this correctly and as **new user** suggests, this excludes "experienced/inexperienced users on other Stack Exchange sites"<sup>*</sup>. I would consider "first questions/answers" on this site to denote exactly that - the first question posted by an individual on [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com). Should this ambiguity be addressed?

<sup>*</sup> See, for example, many [user profiles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) in the 101-126 reputation range (25 reputation span).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only get the 100rep bonus once you have 200rep on one SX account. So you have at least a little experience in the SX site format. These review pages seem to target people who are *new to the SX concept*, not new to (La)TeX (or whatever the particular SX site is about). So this might be status-by-design.

Comment: Great clarification!

Comment: @Werner: I will tag the question now as {status-by-design}, ok?

Comment: That sounds good.